# Unable to send a valid request using React (it is woring with curl)

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, request

I am trying to connect to my small server made using aiohttp. This is a post request, here is what it looks like using HTTPie (it works with curl too): [image: HTTPIE screenshot]
So here is what I tried with react:

```js
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: encodeURIComponent('username=thomas&password=yolo'),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    };
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/login", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log("data:" + data))
```

But this request doesn't work: I get this error on the server side: "username and password fields expected" (server main file src: https://hasteb.in/amucojas.py). 
Here is a screen of my browser: [image: browser]

As you can see in this screeshot, the sent request contains a ":" at the end. Do you think this could be the problem? Did I do something wrong? On which side?

EDIT: also tried to send the same request with these options:

```js
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ "username" : "thomas", "password" : "yolo"}),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    };
```

It looks a bit better in the browser but the server returns me the same error.
Here is the result of curl -v:
[image: curl -v]

Comment: Can you show the contents of the Response tab in the developer tools?

Comment: Did you try typing in the username and password string again? There could be a special/different line-ending character.

Comment: Response: error 400, you should see easily where it is triggered on the hastebin link I gave (l70)

Typing again and again: Yes I tried (directly in the source code), and anyway it should just tell me the password is not the right one

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
const user = {
    username: 'thomas',
    password: 'yolo'
};

const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(user),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}

fetch('http://localhost:8080/login', requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => console.log(response));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a first solution I found on this website. This is probably not the best one since it was designed for react native but this is currently the  working for me:

```js
    var details = {
      'username': 'thomas',
      'password': 'yolo'
    };

    var formBody = [];
    for (var property in details) {
      var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
      var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
      formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
    }
    formBody = formBody.join("&");

    fetch('http://localhost:8080/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
      },
      body: formBody
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => console.log(response));
```

I tried to use URLSearchParams but it didn't work.